# Vertx Websocket not displaying on HTML page

Tags: websocket, vert.x, vertx-eventbus

I'm trying to display messages from a Vertx event bus on an HTML page using Vertx WebSocket. But from my implementation when I test the endpoint on the browser it displays This site can’t be reached. The eventbus publishes radomPrize and the consumer receives them I have seen that on the logs using other implementations. Below is what I have done.

ConsumerController

```
@Controller
public class ConsumerController implements Function<RoutingContext, Uni<Void>> {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ConsumerController.class.getName());
    private final EventBus eventBus;

    public ConsumerController(Router router, EventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
        router.route("/prizes")
                .respond(this);

        router.route("/static/*").handler(StaticHandler.create().setCachingEnabled(false));
    }
    @Override
    public Uni<Void> apply(RoutingContext ctx) {
        ServerWebSocket webSocket = ctx.request().toWebSocketAndAwait();

        if (webSocket != null) {
            LOGGER.info("WebSocket connection established");

            webSocket.textMessageHandler(message -> {
                LOGGER.info("Received WebSocket message: " + message);
            });

            eventBus.consumer("prizes", message -> {
                String prize = (String) message.body();
                LOGGER.info("Sending prize to WebSocket: " + prize);

                webSocket.writeTextMessage("Received Prize: " + prize)
                        .onItem().invoke(() -> {
                            LOGGER.info("Message sent successfully");
                        })
                        .onFailure().invoke(throwable -> {
                            LOGGER.info("Failed to send message: " + throwable.getMessage());
                        })
                        .subscribe().with(
                                ignored -> {},
                                throwable -> LOGGER.info("Subscription failed: " + throwable.getMessage())
                        );
            });
        } else {
            LOGGER.info("WebSocket connection is null");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

PrizeBrokerVerticle

```
@Component
public class PrizeBrokerVerticle extends AbstractVerticle  {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PrizeBrokerVerticle.class.getName());

    private final EventBus eventBus;
    private final List<String> availablePrizes = List.of("Apple", "HP", "Dell");

    public PrizeBrokerVerticle(EventBus eventBus) {
        this.eventBus = eventBus;
    }

    public void start() {
        vertx.setPeriodic(2000, timerId -> {
            String randomPrize = generateRandomPrize();

            eventBus.publish("prizes", randomPrize);
//            LOGGER.info("Prize published to EventBus");
        });
    }

    private String generateRandomPrize() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(availablePrizes.size());
        return availablePrizes.get(index);
    }
}
```

Index.html

Comment: you cant html page a websocket -- have a proper html page route that _makes_ a websocket connection and retrieves the information and then updates the html